# How can I use a google speech to text api key in deployed WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, google-cloud-speech

I have created a C# WPF app that uses google Speech-to-Text API. Currently, on my development machine, I have added an environment variable in windows, which references to the JSON file that google gave me.

Will I need to create that environment variable to every machine I deploy my app or is there a way to somehow store the JSON key on a server and reference it from there?

Comment: There surely is an alternative to have to configure Google Speech-to-Text through environment variables. To answer your question it's important to know who will be the users of your WPF app. Can the users be trusted not to abuse the API key? Because you have to assume they will find it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, [Passing Credentials Using Code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code) helps you.

This is the code copied from there:

```cs
// Some APIs, like Storage, accept a credential in their Create()
// method.
public object AuthExplicit(string projectId, string jsonPath)
{
    // Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying 
    // the private key file.
    var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath);
    var storage = StorageClient.Create(credential);
    // Make an authenticated API request.
    var buckets = storage.ListBuckets(projectId);
    foreach (var bucket in buckets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(bucket.Name);
    }
    return null;
}
// Other APIs, like Language, accept a channel in their Create()
// method.
public object AuthExplicit(string projectId, string jsonPath)
{
    LanguageServiceClientBuilder builder = new LanguageServiceClientBuilder
    {
        CredentialsPath = jsonPath
    };

    LanguageServiceClient client = builder.Build();
    AnalyzeSentiment(client);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had to use SpeechClientBuilder to pass the credentials explicitly and it worked.